# How to display loading info based on clicked delete button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below is working fine by deleting record.

Now Am trying to display text **Loading. deleting in progress...** only for that particular button being clicked.

**Here is my issue**, when I click on a single record button, i can see the text **Loading. deleting in progress...** displayed in all the record instead of showing for that single particular button i clicked.

[image: here is the screenshot]

I have tried using **id** to indicated the clicked row button but cannot get it to work as per below
I set this withing the **handleDeleteRow() function**

```
this.setState({loading_id: false});
this.setState({loading_id: true});
```

**I set this at render**

```
{loading_person.id && <span>Loading. deleting in progress...</span>}
```

**here is the code**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "user 1" },
        { id: "2", name: "user 2"},
        { id: "3", name: "user 3"}
      ]
    });

 this.handleDeleteRow = this.handleDeleteRow.bind(this);
  }



handleDeleteRow = (id) => {
    this.setState({loading: true});
alert(id);
    let data = [...this.state.data];
    data.splice(id, 1);
    this.setState({ 
      data: data
    });
    this.setState({loading: false});
  }




  render() {

const {loading} = this.state;
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map(person => (
              <li key={person.id}>
                {person.name}
                <br />

<button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteRow(person.id)} style={{color:'red'}}>Delete</button>
{loading && <span>Loading. deleting in progress...</span>}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store id of the object being deleted and enable loading indicator based on stored id.
Instead of this.setState({loading: true}), use this in handleDeleteRow:

> this.setState({deletedId: id});

And in render:

> {this.state.deletedId===person.id && Loading. deleting in progress...

Answer (score 1):

Just Toggle Button with loading spinner like this

```
{!loading?<button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteRow(person.id)} style={{color:'red'}}>Delete</button>
: <span>Loading. deleting in progress...</span>}
```